# Every time I try to run my data visualization (bokeh) Flask application, I get a SystemExit

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, data-visualization, bokeh

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html


def get_total_confirmed_us():
    output_file("COVID_19_Data.html")
    country = 'united-states'
    status = 'confirmed'
    url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/{}/status/{}?from=2020-05-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-05-30T00:00:00Z'.format(country, status)
    response = requests.get(url)
    us_confirmed = response.json()
    us_confirmed = pd.DataFrame(us_confirmed)
    plot = figure()
    plot.line(range(len(us_confirmed)), us_confirmed['Cases'])
    show(plot)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def run():
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename = 'COVID_19_Data.html'))


%tb
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5000, use_reloader = False)
```

Every time I run my my Flask app locally, I get a System Exit. Does anyone know how to fix this? I will show you the error below:

```
<ipython-input-1-9f0d70378116> in <module>
     31     app.debug = True
     32     get_ipython().run_line_magic('tb', '')
---> 33     app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5000)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py in run(self, host, port, debug, load_dotenv, **options)
    988 
    989         try:
--> 990             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
    991         finally:
    992             # reset the first request information if the development server

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)    1005         from ._reloader import run_with_reloader  1006 
-> 1007         run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)    1008     else:    1009         inner()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py in run_with_reloader(main_func, extra_files, interval, reloader_type)
    330             reloader.run()
    331         else:
--> 332             sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
    333     except KeyboardInterrupt:
    334         pass

SystemExit: 1

 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)  * Environment: production    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.    Use a production WSGI server instead.  * Debug mode: on  * Restarting with stat An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

I am a beginner with Flask so I do not know what any of this error mean. By the way, I am running this code on Jupyter Notebook and am trying to create a Flask App where I can show my COVID 19 Data Visualization and build up more features once this error is resolved.

Comment: That stack trace shows different code that you posted (32 is new, 33 is different). Can you clarify that first?

Answer (score 0):

check  if you wrote:  app = Flask(**name**, static_folder='static').
also if you have the static folder.

Comment: Thanks, but I wrote that and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a month old, but for future readers, there seems to be no way of doing this. You will have to move everything to an independent `.py` file, then run it independently.